# functions in parallel never executes in Gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have a class that collects functions and returns that in an object of series or parallel.
But none of my functions gets invoked after returned. Execution stops.

**Code that adds functions to the array**:

```
var _result = [];
for(var indx in projects) {
    const process = () => {
        for (var p in getTargets(true)) {
            const filename = getFilename(p);

            log("src", p);
        }
    }

    _result.push(process);
}

return parallel(_result);
```

**Whats logged when returning the _result object**:

```
[
  [Function: process],
  [Function: process],
  [Function: process],
  [Function: process],
  [Function: process],
  [Function: process]
]
```

So it contains the functions, it just never executes them.

The code:

```
class ProcessExec {
    constructor () {
        this.coll = [];
    }

    push (process) {
        this.coll.push(process);
    }

    clear () {
        this.coll = [];
    }

    processes () {
        return this.coll;
    }

    parallel () {
        return parallel(this.coll.map(f => f()));
    }

    series () {
        return series(this.coll.map(f => f()));
    }
}

const distributeProcess = target => {
    const _result = new ProcessExec();
    const getProjects = () => {
        var result = [];
        const distroTargets = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("gulp-creator-targets.json"));

        for (var i = 0; i < distroTargets.projects.length; i++) {
            const project = distroTargets.projects[i];

            if (project.active) {
                const p = () => {
                    return project.base + "//wwwroot//STYLE//Creator";
                }

                result.push(p);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    const projects = getProjects();

    if (isTargetStyle(target)) {
        const baseTargets = [
            "Creator.css",
            "Creator.css.map",
            "Creator.min.css",
            "Creator.min.css.map"
        ]

        const getTargets = (usePath = false) => {
            var result = [];

            for(var index in baseTargets) {
                var trg = baseTargets[index];
                var t = trg;

                if (usePath) {
                    t = targetPath(trgBuild) + "//" + trg;
                }

                result.push(t);
            }

            return result;
        }      

        for(var indx in projects) {
            const proj = projects[indx];
            const process = () => {
                for (var p in getTargets(true)) {
                    const filename = getFilename(p);

                    log("src", p);
                }
            }

            _result.push(process);
        }

        log("Creator", "Distributed to " + projects.length + " projects");
    }
    else if (isTargetScript(target)) {
        log("SCRIPT");
    }
    else {
        throw targetNotSupportedError(target);
    }

    return _result.parallel();
}
```

the function that gets called on Change:

```
const changed = target => {
    if (isTargetStyle(target)) {      
        return series(() => distrProcess(trgStyle));
    }
    else if (isTargetScript(target)) {
        return series(cleanScriptBuildFolder, scriptChangedProcess);
    }
    else {
        throw targetNotSupportedError(target);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular workflow, but what about `return parallel(_result.map(f => f())`?  That would execute each function instead of just returning a reference to the function.

Comment: @Phix yeah that looks right, but I get a AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task never defined: undefined for some reason

Comment: Hmm, maybe because the process function doesn't return anything? Can you add more of your gulp config?

Comment: @Phix just to make some progress I changed so the one process does all the work instead of returning a parallel object with all the processes. but that actually how I want it so I'll continue to try fix it. I'll add more code soon